# Setting Default owner while converting lead ...If Lead is owned by a queue

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I have a process builder in my org which checks if (fieldA = 'XYZ') and then invokes a AutoLeadConversion class (code below).

```
Public class AutoConvertLeads
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)
    {
        LeadStatus CLeadStatus= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];
        List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
        for(id currentlead: LeadIds){

                Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
                Leadconvert.setLeadId(currentlead);                
                Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(CLeadStatus.MasterLabel);
                MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert);
        }

        if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty()) {
            List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert);
        }
    }
}
```

But if i make fieldA = XYZ and that Lead owner is a queue, then it will give error that converted lead can be owned by user only and not queue.

So i set the Account default owner as a User, if owner is a queue while converting.(Modified class)

```
    Public class AutoConvertLeads
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)
    {
        User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE email = 'sonali.hingorani@spjain.org' Limit 1];
        LeadStatus CLeadStatus= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];
        List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
        for(id currentlead: LeadIds){               
                String LeadOwnerId = [SELECT Ownerid FROM Lead WHERE id=:currentlead Limit 1].Ownerid;
                Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
                Leadconvert.setLeadId(currentlead);                
                Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(CLeadStatus.MasterLabel);
                if(LeadOwnerId.startsWith('00G')){
                   Leadconvert.setOwnerId(u.Id);           
                }              
                MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert);
        }

        if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty()) {
            List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert);
        }
    }
}
```

But i am using a query inside a for loop which is a bad practice...So anybody have any idea how to achieve this without query inside loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just query the leads and place them in a map:

```
Public class AutoConvertLeads
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)
    {
        User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE email = 'sonali.hingorani@spjain.org' Limit 1];
        LeadStatus CLeadStatus= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];
        Map<Id, Lead> leads = new Map<Id, Lead>([SELECT OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leadIds]);
        List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
        for(id currentlead: LeadIds){
            Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
            Leadconvert.setLeadId(currentlead);                
            Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(CLeadStatus.MasterLabel);
            // Check lead owner here
            if(leads.get(currentLead).OwnerId.getSObjectType() != User.SObjectType) {
                Leadconvert.setOwnerId(u.Id);
            }
            MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert);
        }
        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will do.....Thanks a ton! But i dont get why did you remove if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty()) { }

Comment: This list could still be empty...correct me if i am wrong :)

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar It is not an error to call Database.convertLead on an empty list. There is no need to check for an empty list.